# Symfony2 - how to search json_array field in findBy

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

Assume i have an array of data contacts,

```
$cont = array("123-123-123","sample@sample.com");
```

Which i stored in symfony2 doctrine field as `json_array` type

```
$person->setContacts($cont); //Which automatically converts into json
```

Now my problem is, while searching the person by contact,

```
$cont['contacts'] = array("123-123-123","sample@sample.com");
or
$cont['contacts'] = json_encode(array("123-123-123","sample@sample.com"));
$person->findBy($cont);
```

Does not yield the correct result, is there any other method to retrieve the data by `json_array` field,sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: can you show your `setContacts` method?

Comment: It is auto generated by doctrine, while we creating the entity

Comment: Serializing data that you need to query is _not_ a good option. Why don't you create a separate entity `Contact`? Or use Value Objects like in [@Guilro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23905138/1237411)?

Answer (score 4):

You should not use JSON to store in database if you want to perform a search on it.

What you are trying to do is basically to persist a value object (you should create a real Contact value object instead of using array).

Then you cam find here several solution to persist value object. http://rosstuck.com/persisting-value-objects-in-doctrine/

The first one (map it yourself) is the same as ZhukV and is applicable even if you keep an array.

Comment: This is not correct in general. For example there is the `jsonb` in postgres. You can query on that efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the json (or jsonb) data type if you are using PostgreSQL > 9.3.

You can read the documentation here ([Datatype JSON Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)).

Answer (score -2):

Searching by JSON - bad idea for SQL databases. You can create a another fields (phone and email).

All values before bind to PDO, auto converting in DBAL\Types, and you must set the really data as parameter (object, array, etc...).

```
$cont['contacts'] = array("123-123-123","sample@sample.com");
$person->findBy($cont);
```

This is a working code. You can see to profiler for view full SQL query.